# EIGEN : Sparse matrix multiplication not producing a pruned result

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

I'm using EIGEN for the sparse matrix optimizations and functions. Everything is "working" fine, except in some case and I can't figure this case out.

Here is the thing :

```
Matrix A
2 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 2

Matrix B
6 3
0 1
2 8

Result
12 6 
0 2 
4 16
```

As you can see, this is the right result, and I'm always having the right result.

The problem is about the values considered as "Non Zero". In this case :

```
SparseMatrix<int, RowMajor> A;
SparseMatrix<int, RowMajor> B;
//Parsing and initializing matrix
SparseMatrix<int, RowMajor> result = A*B;
result.pruned();
cout << result.nonZeros();
```

The result of `nonZeros()` is 5, which is the "normal" case, since Result got only 5 non Zero values.
Now, let's consider this code :

```
SparseMatrix<int, RowMajor> A;
SparseMatrix<int, RowMajor> B;
//Parsing and initializing matrix
SparseMatrix<int, RowMajor> result = (A*B).pruned();
cout << result.nonZeros();
```

The result of `nonZeros()` is 6. I do not understand why, this is the syntax available on [the documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#TutorialSparse_Products).

And now the strangest part is that on very large matrix `result = A*B; result.pruned()` is sometimes ALSO saving 0 as nonZero, but less than if I used `(A*B).pruned();`

I got three questions :

- Why are `result = (A*B).pruned()` and `result=A*B;result.pruned();` giving different results concerning nonZero values (and not effective result, which is right in both case)?
- Why are 0 values from a product sometimes not considered as Zero Values?
- Are you having the same result than me?

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013 and Eigen 3.3.2, using DEBUG mode and targeting WIN32.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :** Benchmark of sparse multiplication with VS2013, DEBUG/Release mode for W32 (With or without SSE2 instruction set, same results in both case); the result is always the right one so i'm not pasting it here, it's not bringing any information. With :

1 = `SparseMatrix<int, RowMajor> resultA = A*B;`

2 = `SparseMatrix<int, RowMajor> resultB = (A*B);resultB.pruned();`

3 = `SparseMatrix<int, RowMajor> resultC = (A*B).pruned();`

**Case 1**

```
Matrix A
2 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 2

Matrix B
5 3
0 1
2 8
```

Expected value = 5

1 = 5

2 = 5

3 = 6

**Case 2**
Matrix are too large, [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=68463106545818632889&t=6846310654581863288912929) is the file

Expected value = 0

1 = 1444

2 = 1444

3 = 0

As you can see, depending both on the input and the way I'm calling functions, the result is optimized or not, and none of 1, 2 or 3 are working in every case.

**EDIT² :** Problem fixed by ggael solution (thanks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer (below) was wrong. Problem fixed [there](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/3784049266ff/).

> This is because you are targeting win32 and thus you are hitting
>   classical issues with the extended precision of the FPU registers. By
>   default, `pruned` remove entries that are strictly equal to 0, but
>   with the FPU, it could be that a non zero becomes zero only after
>   being copied from its register to memory. Update your compiler flags
>   to either target SSE2 instruction set, or to kill the extra FPU
>   precision.

Comment: I just changed compiler flag to SSE2 instruction set, and still having 0 considered as Zero values. What do you mean by killing the extra FPU precision? Writing something like a converter ? I made a benchmark, and following the results I'm not sure it's a precision problem because depending on the order you're calling the functions, the results are different. I'm going to add this in the first post.

Comment: You are right. Problem fixed in 3.3 and devel branch.